# Is it possible to move all figure captions from above to below in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, caption

I have a 300 page MS Word document containing around 50 figures. I originally positioned all captions above each figure. Now I need to move all the captions below the figures while retaining the same formatting (such as being italicized, colored, same font, etc). What is the most effective way to do this? (I am not familiar with how to use macros so I need basic instructions)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a wildcard find and replace, with 2 parts (in the  replace you then swap the order of the parts).  In the example below, I've assumed that your caption starts with "Figure ..." and ends with a paragraph (^13), so the first part captures all text from the start of Figure to the end of that paragraph.  I then assume that your picture is on the immediately following paragraph.  The second part (*^13) is everything from after the end of the Figure paragraph (ie start of your second paragraph) to the next paragraph mark.  \1 is the first part of the find (Figure*^13) where asterisk is all characters, and \2 is the second part of the find (the paragraph with the image).  In the replace, you see it says \2\1 which means replace with the second part followed by the first part (ie swapping the order of your caption and image).

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. Figure captions are linked to figures with some kind of coding which means that when you update the Table of Contents, any changes in the caption will also be updated. Would this method upset the link between the caption and the figure?

Comment: Also, wouldn't you have to do this for each figure? one by one. In which case I could just do it all manually

Comment: I would step through them one by one (so you don't pick up references within paragraph text itself to Figures), but it's very quick with accelerator keys (underlined on the dialog buttons) - ALT f for find next, then ALT r for replace.  I just did a test and table of contents wasn't affected - still includes them when I refresh after doing the find and replace.  I suspect you'd probably still need to do some formatting tidying up - eg keep with next paragraph on the figure itself paragraph as the caption is now below it.  Before making big changes, I always use a copy of the doc and do a test.